# gulp-inject not working with event-stream

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower, gulp-inject, event-stream

gulp-inject does not working with event-stream.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var es = require('event-stream');

var config = {
    sassDir: './resources/assets/sass',
    jsPath: './resources/app',
    fontDir: './resources/fonts',
    imageDir: './resources/images',
    bowerDir: './bower_components'
};

gulp.task('index', function () {
    return gulp.src('./resources/index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(mainBowerFiles('**/*.js'), {read: false}), {name: 'bower'}))
      .pipe(inject(es.merge(gulp.src(config.jsPath + '/**/*.js', {read: false}))))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'));
});
```

The result coming like this.

```
<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="/resources/app/core.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/app/first-folder/01.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/app/second-folder/02.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->
```

Unfortunately the `mainBowerFiles('**/*.js')` do not merge with `inject(es.merge(gulp.src(config.jsPath + '/**/*.js', {read: false})))`

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want to happen. What does your HTML look like before and what do you want it to look like afterwards?

Comment: And why do you use `{name:'bower'}` when you don't seem to have a `<!-- bower:js -->` section?

Comment: @SvenSchoenung even if remove`{name:'bower'}`, the result is the same. please have a look attached screenshot in the question

Comment: @SvenSchoenung HTML before look like this `<!-- inject:js -->
 <!-- endinject -->`

Comment: @SvenSchoenung  I was just following this instruction https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject#injecting-all-files-for-development

Comment: You didn't follow that correctly. That example clearly has a `<!-- bower:js -->` section before the `<!-- inject:js -->` section.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung yup, it works now :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're invoking `inject()` **twice** with two different sources (the main bower files and the files in `resources/app`), but you want both sources to be injected into the same section.

What you need to do is call `inject()` **once** with the already merged sources:

```
gulp.task('index', function () {
  return gulp.src('./resources/index.html')
    .pipe(inject(es.merge(
      gulp.src(mainBowerFiles('**/*.js'), {read: false}),
      gulp.src(config.jsPath + '/**/*.js', {read: false})
    )))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'));
});
```

**EDIT:** If you want to keep the order of the files you can use [`streamqueue`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamqueue) instead of `es.merge()`:

```
var streamqueue = require('streamqueue');

gulp.task('index', function () {
  return gulp.src('./resources/index.html')
    .pipe(inject(streamqueue({ objectMode: true },
      gulp.src(mainBowerFiles('**/*.js'), {read: false}),
      gulp.src(config.jsPath + '/**/*.js', {read: false})
    )))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'));
});
```

Comment: awesome, it works but the listing is mixed with bower and customjs :(